# Docker compose global level logging

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I know for the latest docker compose, we can specify logging on a per service basis. eg :-

```
version: '2'

services:
  Sachin:
   image: hike/ubuntu:14.04
   volumes:
     - .:/testDocker
   working_dir: /testDocker
   logging:
    driver: "json-file"
    options:
     max-size: "25m"
     max-file: "2"
command: python -u test.py
```

I have a large number of containers in my compose file. I can specify the logging config for the docker daemon itself. I just wanted to know if it is possible to specify the logging configuration on the global level for the docker compose file. Something like this

```
version: '2'

services:
  Sachin:
   image: hike/ubuntu:14.04
   volumes:
     - .:/testDocker
   working_dir: /testDocker
logging:
 driver: "json-file"
 options:
  max-size: "25m"
  max-file: "2"
command: python -u test.py
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could also configure the Docker default for this, all your container will have the configuration (that you can override per container).

Here an example of solution with YAML anchor:

```
version: "2"

services:

  proxy:
    build: proxy
    image: kinoulink/proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    container_name: ktv_manager_proxy
    environment:
        - HTTP_AUTH_PASSWORD=$KTV_MANAGER_PASSWORD
    logging: &logging
      driver: "awslogs"
      options:
      awslogs-region: eu-west-1
      awslogs-group: docker

  rancher:
    image: rancher/server:v1.1.3
    volumes:
      - rancher_mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - rancher_cattle:/var/lib/cattle
    labels:
      ktv.infra.proxy.domain: 'rancher'
      ktv.infra.proxy.port: '8080'
    logging:
      <<: *logging
```

From v3.4 (as @tekHedd said), you can use "extension field" syntax:

```
version: "3.4"

x-logging: 
      &default-logging
      driver: "awslogs"
      options:
      awslogs-region: eu-west-1
      awslogs-group: docker

services:
proxy:
    build: proxy
    image: kinoulink/proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    container_name: ktv_manager_proxy
    environment:
        - HTTP_AUTH_PASSWORD=$KTV_MANAGER_PASSWORD
    logging: *default-logging

  rancher:
    image: rancher/server:v1.1.3
    volumes:
      - rancher_mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - rancher_cattle:/var/lib/cattle
    labels:
      ktv.infra.proxy.domain: 'rancher'
      ktv.infra.proxy.port: '8080'
    logging: *default-logging
```

Comment: Note that docker-compose v3.4 allows "extension fields" https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extension-fields, which allows you to define YAML anchors outside of the container configuration, really handy.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible at this time. You can use YAML anchors to inject the same struct into each service instead of repeating it.